# how to pipe a file into stream using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, apache-nifi

I am trying to redirect my xls file output to a stream but i am facing error.

Below is the code i am using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import codecs

import datetime

import decimal

import csv

import sys

import xlrd

def main(self):
    # We need to do this dance here, because we aren't writing through agate.
    if six.PY2:
        stream = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(self.output_file)
    else:
        stream = self.output_file

def dump_xls(data,active_worksheet):
                active_worksheet.append(data)
     file_name = "temp.xls"


     reader = csv.reader(self.input_file,delimiter=",")

     workbook  = openpyxl.Workbook()
     worksheet = workbook.active
     for i in reader:
         dump_xls(i,worksheet)
     workbook.save(file_name)

def launch_new_instance():
    utility = CSVXLS()
    utility.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    launch_new_instance

()
```

I already have a input stream and all the stream information . How could i convert my output file into stream so that data is visible at the output .

I am new to python, any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks !!!

Comment: I cant see `input stream`, can you give your full code? what error you are facing?

Comment: @Nilesh i have edited the question please find the full code in question

Comment: i am not getting any error this is working fine fine output as file but my requirement is to have output as a stream and this where i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know I understand what `stream` are you looking for, but `StringIO` is also a stream, and you can write like

```
import StringIO
...
...
s_io = StringIO.StringIO() # Declare stream
for i in reader:
    dump_xls(i,worksheet)
    s_io.write(i) # Write to stream.
```

At end, `s_io` will represent the `stream`